# Set Location of window to a data-rel="dialog"

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a link that I want to link to a *data-rel="dialog"* but before doing that I have to check that the data is inserted correctly, so if it is I do a `window.location = #dialog_page` but then the page is not displayed as a dialog, even though that link has `data-rel="dialog"` attribute.

Is there a way by javascript to change the location and still listen to the `data-rel` attribute?

Thanks.

[EDIT]

This is the button Im checking stuff after it's been clicked:

```
<a alt="#pop_address" data-rel="dialog" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" class="check forward" data-inline="true" data-role="button">Continuar >></a>
```

And this is the code Im using to change the location:

```
window.location = $(this).attr('alt');
```

Im using the alt of the anchor instead of href, so it doesnt redirect before checking.

And after the answer I got I tried this:

```
$.mobile.changePage($('#pop_address'));
```

But it doesnt make the page a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to programmatically opening the dialog as opposed to just having it open directly through an anchor tag's href attribute, you can take a look at the [changePage() method](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html)

So then you would simply call

`$.mobile.changePage($("#dialog_page"));`

or

`$.mobile.changePage($("#dialog_page"), { /* options */ });`

whenever you determine that it is ok to open the dialog.

Comment: I've set that link have a data-rel="dialog" and after using "changePage" it still shows as a normal page and not as a dialog

Comment: Could you post some of the markup and javascript code you're using?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to have any problems, but here is a simple fiddle with a working dialog being opened with changePage(), maybe it will help: http://jsfiddle.net/rXRMZ/14/

Answer (score 0):

a little late here, but when you're loading a page through javascript (be it via the $.changePage() method or window.location()) no links are being clicked to initiate the transition, therefor your data-rel isn't being considered.

Instead you have to include it in options object of the $.changePage() method...

```
 $.mobile.changePage('#page-patient_info',{
                       transition:'pop', 
                       role:'dialog'
                     });
```